# ItemControl DataTemplate with UIElement list

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm trying to develop library of user controls that arranges multiple UIElements in specific way. I use ItemControl to show list of UIElements. I want to surround every item from item control with Stack.
I would like to use my library more or less this manner.

```
  <pcLayouts:ListLayout>

      <pcLayouts:ListLayout.ParentItems>
          <TextBlock Width="145">1</TextBlock>
          <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
          <TextBlock>3</TextBlock>
      </pcLayouts:ListLayout.ParentItems>

   </pcLayouts:ListLayout>
```

I declared dependency property in backing class ListLayout cs and xaml files.

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ParentItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>), typeof(ColumnLayout),
            new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<UIElement>()));
...
        public ObservableCollection<UIElement> ParentItems
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ParentItemsProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ParentItemsProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ParentItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE??/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

It seems DataTemplate isn't used at all when binding to `Binding ParentItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}`. How can I use this data template or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `ItemsControl.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` returns `true` for `UIElement`. Normally a ContentPresenter is used which generates the DataTemplate.

If you insist on using DataTemplate you create a new class derived from ItemsControl and override `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` to return false.

Comment: Thanks overloading done the trick although you seem to imply that this style isn't the preferred one. Care to point to more appropriate method?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but typically data templates are used to generate UIElements for data types (say I have a string I would have a DataTemplate to generate a TextBlock).

If you know the type of your UIElement you could use ItemContainerStyle, or you could use ItemContainerStyleSelector.